# DropDownListFor not selecting the right value on an Edit screen

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, html-helper, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm using a dropdown list for a form. It works and saves just fine when I create a form. But when I load it into the Edit screen, the correct option isn't being selected by default. Instead, the first option is being selected.

I put a breakpoint at the line in the View to see if the id/value for the property is right, which it is. I'm just not sure if it's the code in the View that's wrong or how I'm passing it through the controller.

I used DropDownList before and it worked okay, but for validation purposes I switched to DropDownListFor and I immediately encountered this problem.

**View (Edit)**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Item_ID, (SelectList)ViewBag.Item_ID, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

**Controller**

```
List<ItemInfo> itemIDItems = dbContext.Items.OrderBy(item => item.Item_Title).ToList<ItemInfo>();
ViewBag.Item_ID = new SelectList(itemIDItems, "Item_ID", "Item_Title", object.Item_ID);
```

**Model (Object, generated through EF)**

```
public int Obj_ID { get; set; }
...
public Nullable<int> Item_ID { get; set; }
...
public virtual Items Items { get; set; }
```

**Model (Items, generated through EF)**

```
public int Item_ID { get; set; }
public string Item_Title { get; set; }
```

Comment: please put your model also

Comment: the using of Viewbag is not in the correct direction, I think you need to add property to the Model to represent the selected value of the dropdownlist

Comment: and please also post the `ItemInfo` class

Comment: Models/class have been added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the name of the `ViewBag` property so it does not match the name of the property your binding to. For example your GET method should be

```cs
var model = // get your existing model
List<ItemInfo> itemIDItems = dbContext.Items.OrderBy(item => item.Item_Title).ToList<ItemInfo>();
ViewBag.ItemList = new SelectList(itemIDItems, "Item_ID", "Item_Title");
return View(model);
```

Note that the 4th parameter of the `SelectList` constructor is unnecessary (it's ignored by the `DropDownListFor()` method) because its the value of the property your binding to that determines which option is selected.

And the view will be

```cs
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Item_ID, (SelectList)ViewBag.ItemList, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

If the value of `Item_ID` matches the value of one of the options, then that option will be selected.